# Is $d$ topologically equivalent to the usual metric on $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: metric-spaces

> Let $d$ be  a function  defined on $\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}$ by
>
> $$d(z,z')  = \begin{cases}  0 &\text{if} \; z= z' \\\\ |z| + |z'| &\text{if}\; z \neq z' \end{cases}$$
>
> Is  $d$ topologically equivalent  to the usual metric on $\mathbb{C}$?

My attempt:  I know that  $d$  is  a metric on $\mathbb{C}$ but here im confusing  that "Is  $d$ topologically equivalent  to the usual metric on $\mathbb{C}$?

Any hints/solution ?

Comment: Two metrics are "topologically equivalent" if they give the same open sets.  And you can show that two metrics are "topologically equivalent" if and only if for two open sets, U and V, defined by one metric, such that V is a subset of U, there exist an open set, W, defined by the other metric, such that W is a subset of U and V is  subset of W: $V\subset W\subset U$.

Comment: Hint: how many points are distance $1$ away from $2i$?

Comment: @user247327 i thinks  u r  talking about comparison

Comment: @TheoBendit  we  will get infinite point

Comment: @jasmine Find me one such point then. (Don't say $i$, because $d(i, 2i) = |i| + |2i| = 3$).

Comment: @TheoBendit i was  eating breakfast,,,,sorry for late  reply,,, that mean  there  is no points    so d is not  topologically equivalent to the usual metric on $\mathbb{C}$???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably review the definition of "topologically equivalent".  But one characterization is that two metrics are topologically equivalent iff they have the same convergent sequences.

Consider the sequence $x_n = 1 + \frac{1}{n}$.  Does it converge to $1$ with respect to the usual metric on $\mathbb{C}$?  Does it converge to $1$ with respect to this new metric $d$?

For that matter, with respect to $d$, is there *any* sequence that converges to $1$?  For any $z_0 \ne 0$, is there any sequence that converges to $z_0$?

Another characterization of topologically equivalent metrics is that they have the same open sets. Is $\{1\}$ an open set with respect to the usual metric?  With respect to $d$?

Comment: i thinks  both  $\{x_n\}$   converges  to $1 $  in new  metric and usual metric  but$ \{1\} $ is not open  in usual @Nate eldredge

Comment: @jasmine: Look again.  $x_n$ does not converge to $1$ in the metric $d$.  If it did, you would have $d(x_n, 1) \to 0$, but what is $d(x_n, 1)$?  And you're right that $\{1\}$ is not open in the usual metric, but in the $d$ metric, it is open.